# Jmeter add custom data to report dashboard

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

Couple of questions regarding the jmeter report dashboard.

I want to modify the **index.html.fmkr** in the following way: at the **"Test and Report informations"** i want to add new rows with my custom data.
I see that the rows are like so:

```
<tr>
    <td>Source file</td>
    <td>${testFile!""}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Start Time</td>
    <td>${beginDate!""}</td>
</tr>
```

I am curious where are the **${testFile!""}, ${beginDate!""}** taken from, and if i can use my own ?

Comment: I did. i did not have enough reputation at first, this is a new account :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testFile` is the jtl file used to generate the dashboard

`beginDate` is the start date of the test

Both are added to JMeter dashboard internally and can't be customized.

You can customize part of dashboardaccording to [Configuring Dashboard Generation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration):

> All report generator properties can be found in file reportgenerator.properties. To customize these properties, you should copy them in user.properties file and modify them.

For example you can add to your `user.properties` file a overriding line of dashboard title:

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title=My Customized Dashboard
```

Comment: Thanks. The answer i was looking for was if those variables are JMeter internally or not. Guess i have to come up with a new plan